# US Individual Income averages by county and age brackets

Tags: data-request, us-census, income

I'm looking to create an average income for individuals based on their location and age. I have the average income by US county (census data), but I'm looking to combine this with age. Where can I find average income by age bracket and location? Gender income by state would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

i think your choices are the https://www.census.gov/did/www/saipe/ for estimates or the census summary file #2 for real numbers--
http://www.census.gov/prod/cen2010/doc/sf1.pdf#page=9

```
2010 Census Summary File 2 (SF 2). Files containing cross-tabulations of information on age, sex, 
household relationship, household type, household size, family type, family size, group quarters 
population, occupancy status, tenure, etc., for many race and Hispanic or Latino groups and American 
Indian and Alaska Native tribes. The file for each state includes data down to the census tract level, if there 
are 100 or more people of the specified population group in a given geographic area. Other tabulations 
are available only down to the county level (release: December 2011–April 2012). SF 2 was updated with 
national-level data (release: May 2012) and urban/rural data (planned release: January 2013). Files and 
reference maps will be made available through American FactFinder
```

if you can tolerate PUMAs instead of counties, then you can run the data directly off of the ACS

http://www.asdfree.com/search/label/american%20community%20survey%20(acs)

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps - [Quandl's Tax Policy Center](https://www.quandl.com/data/TPC) database shows median income by age range, during a certain time frame and has data on median income outside cities vs metropolitan areas. You can search for "age income" within the database to see the all the different datasets. Or, actually, you can try going to this link directly: https://www.quandl.com/data/TPC?keyword=age%20income

[Disclosure: I work for Quandl]